# Xamarin iOS build crashes only on TestFlight

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, crash, ms-app-analytics

I have an app that has been working fine in production and on Testflight. However, recently our customer upgraded to iOS 15 and the app started crashing for them on startup. I looked into this and was able to reproduce the crash by deploying directly to a device. The cause of the crash ended up being related to the Microsoft AppCenter Crash Analytics Nuget package we were using. The problem related to some namespaces, that were protected by iOS, being used by the Microsoft Analytics package. The fix was simply to upgrade the package and after deploying to the device I was no longer able to reproduce the crash.

However, when I uploaded the build to Testflight the app still crashes on startup. Since I am unable to debug or even get past the splashscreen I cannot get any useful logs or crash reports. I have the iOS crash log but it is not particularly useful since there is no backtrace. I will post the crash here anyways, in case someone can make sense of it.

I have since tried a myriad of things to try and resolve this issue. One of which being removing the MS Analytics package entirely from the project. Another being upgrading all of the nuget packages in my app to their latest version.

There are old versions of the app that do not crash on Testflight, but when I revert my code back to those version commits and build/upload to Testflight those new versions crash on startup. This leads me to believe there is something wrong with my build setup (I use a windows machine connected to a Mac to build). However, I can build other apps with the same setup that do not crash. I am at a loss! I have a hard time believing that this is a completely separate issue from the MS Analytics issue that I already resolved, but maybe I am wrong?

So in summary:

- Has anyone experienced this issue or something similar? And what did you do to fix it?
- Is Testflight and/or the Mac that I'm building off of capable of adding dependencies that are no longer in my app into the Release build (like as if they were cached somewhere)??
- If no one has experienced this, can someone at least give me some troubleshooting tips? I am running out of ideas.

Thank you in advance!

```
    Incident Identifier: 000A8232-87D1-4991-B66A-EB01EF57A2EF
Beta Identifier:     F8073B0C-689B-42D8-8945-BE7C9F40F112
Hardware Model:      iPad5,3
Process:             MYAPP.iOS [710]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/024CEC96-F13C-40F6-9100-D583526450D7/MYAPP.iOS.app/MYAPP.iOS
Identifier:          com.MYCOMPANY.MYAPP.atco
Version:             1.0.95 (1.95)
AppStoreTools:       13C90b
AppVariant:          1:iPad5,3:15
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.MYCOMPANY.MYAPP.atco [474]

Date/Time:           2022-01-25 11:38:13.0492 -0500
Launch Time:         2022-01-25 11:38:11.4917 -0500
OS Version:          iPhone OS 15.1 (19B74)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called


Thread 0 name:  tid_103 Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1baa369e8 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab81824 pthread_kill + 208
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x18c0600b4 abort + 120
3   MYAPP.iOS                              0x1040920cc xamarin_unhandled_exception_handler + 60
4   MYAPP.iOS                              0x103f5906c mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook + 132
5   MYAPP.iOS                              0x103eee1e4 mono_handle_exception_internal + 5664
6   MYAPP.iOS                              0x103eecbb8 mono_handle_exception + 56
7   MYAPP.iOS                              0x103ee2934 mono_arm_throw_exception + 360
8   MYAPP.iOS                              0x1014c654c throw_exception + 172
9   MYAPP.iOS                              0x1010f8664 MYAPP_iOS_Application_Main_string__ + 52
10  MYAPP.iOS                              0x101486b80 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 272
11  MYAPP.iOS                              0x103efff2c mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1136
12  MYAPP.iOS                              0x103fb9b08 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 148
13  MYAPP.iOS                              0x103fbfdbc mono_runtime_exec_main_checked + 128
14  MYAPP.iOS                              0x103ede33c mono_jit_exec + 376
15  MYAPP.iOS                              0x10409a940 xamarin_main + 1024
16  MYAPP.iOS                              0x1010f85b4 main + 76
17  dyld                                   0x109560190 start + 444

Thread 1 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.UIKit.KeyboardManagement
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1baa316f4 __ulock_wait + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1818536ec _dlock_wait + 52
2   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1818534d8 _dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow$VARIANT$mp + 52
3   libdispatch.dylib                      0x181860480 __DISPATCH_WAIT_FOR_QUEUE__ + 320
4   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1818600a4 _dispatch_sync_f_slow + 136
5   UIKitCore                              0x18420ccb4 __37-[_UIRemoteKeyboards startConnection]_block_invoke_3 + 112
6   CoreFoundation                         0x181b758d0 __invoking___ + 144
7   CoreFoundation                         0x181b915a8 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 300
8   Foundation                             0x1832c6d70 __NSXPCCONNECTION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_REPLY_BLOCK__ + 20
9   Foundation                             0x1832e6518 -[NSXPCConnection _decodeAndInvokeReplyBlockWithEvent:sequence:replyInfo:] + 552
10  Foundation                             0x1832c2bbc __88-[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:orArguments:count:methodSignature:selector:withProxy:]_block_invoke_3 + 208
11  libxpc.dylib                           0x1dababcc8 _xpc_connection_reply_callout + 60
12  libxpc.dylib                           0x1daba0004 _xpc_connection_call_reply_async + 76
13  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1818b3210 _dispatch_client_callout3 + 16
14  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18186c050 _dispatch_mach_msg_async_reply_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 352
15  libdispatch.dylib                      0x181858fa4 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 340
16  libdispatch.dylib                      0x181859bb4 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 456
17  libdispatch.dylib                      0x181863750 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 632
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab75e84 _pthread_wqthread + 284
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759f0 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 2 name:  SGen worker
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1baa314f0 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab7dbfc _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 1216
2   MYAPP.iOS                              0x10405ccd4 thread_func + 236
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab773a4 _pthread_start + 116
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759fc thread_start + 8

Thread 3 name:  Finalizer
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1baa30b4c semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   MYAPP.iOS                              0x103f5c474 finalizer_thread + 344
2   MYAPP.iOS                              0x10400760c start_wrapper_internal + 356
3   MYAPP.iOS                              0x104007490 start_wrapper + 68
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab773a4 _pthread_start + 116
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759fc thread_start + 8

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1baa30b10 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1baa31134 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                         0x181b5bac0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 368
3   CoreFoundation                         0x181b5fba8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1184
4   CoreFoundation                         0x181b72d7c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
5   Foundation                             0x1832ab00c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 232
6   Foundation                             0x1832ea18c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 88
7   UIKitCore                              0x184322d58 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 512
8   Foundation                             0x1832f7efc __NSThread__start__ + 792
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab773a4 _pthread_start + 116
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759fc thread_start + 8

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 20:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 21:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 22:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 23:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 24:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 25:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 26:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 27:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 28:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 29:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 30:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 31:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dab759e8 start_wqthread + 0


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x00000000000001f0   x5: 0x0000000109752670   x6: 0x000000000000006c   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x00000001095a8580   x9: 0x83715f9c5efc65bc  x10: 0x0000000000000040  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x0000000109725da0  x13: 0x000000010b0f19cb  x14: 0x0000000000000060  x15: 0x0000000080000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00000000000fbf80  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000103  x21: 0x00000001095a8660  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x000000010a015a00
   x24: 0x000000010b0f19c8  x25: 0x000000016eebe730  x26: 0x0000000000000001  x27: 0x000000010440c6a8
   x28: 0x0000000000ffffff   fp: 0x000000016eebd930   lr: 0x00000001dab81824
    sp: 0x000000016eebd910   pc: 0x00000001baa369e8 cpsr: 0x40000000
   far: 0x000000010dad0094  esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault

Binary Images:
       0x1baa30000 -        0x1baa61fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <28a82cbdb2103662af9e636819d8909a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
       0x1dab71000 -        0x1dab84fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <ce7eb78851553c3888d812f1419fa5fa> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
       0x18c041000 -        0x18c0bbfff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <5700e26c19b735c9b739e62c325f4fcc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
       0x100f40000 -        0x1041e3fff MYAPP.iOS arm64  <f6534b39802d3520a881546f47b6fd61> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/024CEC96-F13C-40F6-9100-D583526450D7/MYAPP.iOS.app/MYAPP.iOS
       0x109548000 -        0x10959bfff dyld arm64  <5e7ef5771cc5369aa04d28fbba883086> /usr/lib/dyld
       0x18184f000 -        0x1818d1fff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <56aa6e938d8e32feac73d3e79b1ba2f5> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
       0x183eb9000 -        0x185642fff UIKitCore arm64  <fb5c2d366a053355b898d8d3c163d02e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
       0x181b55000 -        0x181f8ffff CoreFoundation arm64  <ea9c1df294c7379bbf8d970335b1552f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
       0x183293000 -        0x183573fff Foundation arm64  <86d8a58db71f34c683e0014b2b835f1d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
       0x1dab93000 -        0x1dabc5fff libxpc.dylib arm64  <0d9c930f4a4b352c988d4b52a1636fb2> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib

EOF
```

Comment: Does the crash still happen if you remove MS Analytics package ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried removing the pack entirely and it still crashes. I am beginning to think that the problem may be one of a missing permission in the info.plist but I can't find out what I should add.

Comment: Try to integrate [App Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/crashes/xamarin) in your project , it can diagnose what's going wrong on startup.

Comment: Sorry, by MS Analytics I am referring to the Microsoft App Center. That is what was causing the issue in the first place. And I believe its crashing before the App Center is even instantiated.

Comment: You are not alone... we have the *exact* same situation.

Comment: hopefully this helps, but after doing some research I found that we were calling NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource() in our AppDelegate for a BundleResource. This used to work but I guess something in the upgrade to iOS 14 or 15 broke it. But anyways removing that code fixed the problem for me. 

To be clear the NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource() wasn't throwing an exception but it was returning null and then our code was doing something with that null value that threw and exception.

Comment: Had a similar issue, but it was caused by some generics in sqlite. The way I found it was to just deploy a release build to my phone and then I got the stacktrace from there. The solution was to enable "Mono interpreter" under iOS Build in the project options.

Comment: I'm having this issue too. @LasseP How did you "deploy a release build" to your phone without going through TestFlight?

Comment: @ChuckKrutsinger It's possible without using testflight, you need to setup a development provisioning profile, either free or through the apple developer account, then connect your phone via usb or wireless to the Mac and then you can deploy a debug or release build straight to the phone - see the provision guides here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/